# iOS app with FBAudienceNetwork on AdMob mediation: error "No such module FBAudienceNetwork"

Tags: ios, xcode, admob, cocoapods, facebook-audience-network

I am trying to configure FB Audience Network with AdMob mediation on iOS, using Cocoapods, but I get a strange error:

```
No such module 'FBAudienceNetwork'
```

[image]

This is what I placed in the podfile:

```
pod 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK'
pod 'FBAudienceNetwork'
pod 'GoogleMobileAdsMediationFacebook'
```

I tried to clean the build folder and to restart Xcode, but I still get the same error.

Any suggestion of what I should do?

Comment: Afaik, there's no need to pull `FBAudienceNetwork`, just a `pod 'GoogleMobileAdsMediationFacebook'` should suffice as it would pull the required dependency. Also try `pod install --repo-update`.

Comment: @Darshan you are right. I had actually tried even without `pod 'FBAudienceNetwork'`, but the warning was still appearing. Now, after removing the the pods list, running `pod install`, readding the pod list and running`pod install` again, the warning magically went away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you followed the steps correctly. A lot of the time, this issue might come up due to some other dependencies or conflicting files. Ways to debug:

- Run `pod update`.
- Run `sudo gem install cocoapods` to get the latest cocapods version and run `pod update`.
- Clean install, remove all the pod dependencies in the `Podfile`, and run `pod install`. Put the dependencies back and run `pod install` again to get a clean install.
- Similar to the above but the difference is that you install each pod individually.

Hope it helps.

If you are ever in the market to track your ads or get resources on how to set up some ads have a look at [Motics](https://motics.vivushub.com/) or [Resources](https://motics.vivushub.com/blog/).

Comment: after following your steps, the warning went away, thanks!